# React-Native-Router-Flux: Hide back-button text-label

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm looking for a way to hide the *text-label* of the *back button* on *navigation bar* in `React-Native-Router-Flux`.

The `headerLeft` `prop` isn't serving the purpose and setting `left={()=>null}` hides the button itself (along with the title)

---

`React-Native` `0.46.4`

Answer (score 5):

Setting `headerBackTitleVisible` to `false` worked for me.

I've tested this in react-navigation v5.

```
<HomeStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
      }}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried setting `backTitle = null` and also `backTitle = ""` without success.

As mentioned on [RNRF](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) `GitHub` [thread #2219](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2219), setting `prop` `backTitle = " "` (space in quotes) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

> headerBackTitle: null,

```
SetupThreeScreen: {
    screen: SetupThreeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: "Setup",
        headerBackTitle: null,
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1abc9c',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#ccc',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        }
    }
},
```